# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 Gantt Charts

Tags: sharepoint-2010, gantt-chart

I know that Sharepoint has some support for Gantt Charts (Gantt view for tasks). What I'm looking for is way to provide advanced task relations (FF: finish to finish, FS: finish to start, etc.) Is there any way to provide it or is there a free component for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I have used Microsoft Charting controls which is free. The nearest chart I could find similar to a Gantt Chart was a Range Bar Chart: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456745.aspx

If you plan on using Microsoft Chart controls, here is a basic tutorial on how to implement it within SharePoint: http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2009/12/03/Microsoft-Chart-and-SharePoint-2007.aspx

Comment: I don't need a Gantt chart but its good to know that there is at last a free charting tool. Microsoft chart looks similar to the Dundas charts. BTW, the link your provided on adding MS Charts in SharePoint is for 2007. Will it work for 2010?

Comment: Maybe a question to ask the blog author. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't since the web.config between 2007 and 2010 are similar.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this addresses the issue. SharePoint has built-in Gantt charts with FS relationships, the whole point of the question is advanced task relationships (FF,SF,SS).

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you are looking for a free component, you can take a JavaScript or Flash charting tool, then link it to a SharePoint list (for example using Web Services or REST). Maybe try JSGantt or FusionCharts.